# How to correctly garbage collect an array of class instances?

Tags: javascript, class, garbage-collection

I want to use the following code to store anonymous class instances; is the `cleanup()` function the correct way to ensure nothing is left dangling in memory?

```
var instances = [];

// example Class
function Ugh() {}

Ugh.prototype.stop = function() {
   // do stuff
};

// push some anonymous instances
instances.push(new Ugh());
instances.push(new Ugh());
instances.push(new Ugh());

// code I'm unsure of, is is correct?
function cleanup() {
  instances.forEach(function(item, i, arr) { 
    item.stop();
    arr[i] = null; // nullify the 'pointer'
  });
  instances.length = 0; // is this needed?
}

cleanup();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point, they will all be garbage collected automatically when `instances` go out of scope

Comment: It's node code and every module is wrapped in a factory function, so scope is never lost.

Comment: It's not worth the trouble doing what you're doing. You don't even know when the garbage collection will happen. If scope is never lost, design your code so that it goes out of scope faster. When your script finishes running, the objects will be destroyed. The whole point of garbage collection is doing what you're doing for you.

Comment: If you empty the array by setting its `.length` to 0 anyway, there's no need to put `null` at every index before.